# Magento layout: load only a single block

Tags: magento

Is there a way in magento to create a block and call its `toHtml()` method **without** having to load the entire layout object.

For example, in one of my ajax controllers i want to send a certain block as json output and i am not interested in any other blocks but i am forced to do the following:

```
$this->loadLayout();
$this->getLayout()->getBlock('my_block_name')->toHtml();
```

Which loads the entire layout which seems unnecessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
$layout = Mage::getSingleton('core/layout');
$html = $layout
            ->createBlock('module/block_type')
            ->setTemplate('template/file.phtml')
            ->toHtml();
```

From your code, it looks as though you are in a controller so you could shorten the code a little to the following (absolutely no difference in functionality, simply 1 less line of code)...

```
$html = $this->getLayout()
             ->createBlock('module/block_type')
             ->setTemplate('template/file.phtml')
             ->toHtml();
```

Answer (score 8):

I just accomplished this like so:

In my layout XML for my module:

```
<mymodule_ajax_action>
    <block type="core/template_facade" name="root" template="path/to/template/file.phtml"/>
</mymodule_ajax_action>
```

By naming the block "root", it replaced the entire layout with just this template file.

So in my controller:

```
public function actionAction() {
    $this->loadLayout();
    $this->renderLayout();
}
```

returns just that block.

Comment: Great solution! In case anyone forgets, the XML identifier needs to be all lowercase: `public function fooBarBazAction` -> `<mymodule_ajax_foobarbaz>`